# how to make date selected in certain format is the date saved?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

As the subject stated, I want to make the date selected in `dd-mm-yyyy` format in my web application develop using asp.net mvc framework is the date saved to the table in mysql database.
Here is the 'scenario':
In the date filling field, I make a format `dd-mm-yyyy`, and use datetimepicker to help user select the date, but it seems mySQL use mm-dd-yyyy when save that data, so when I choose `12 February 2012` (in the filling field it shows `12-02-2012`), it will be saved as `2 December 2012`.
What should I do so make mySQL understand that I want to save 12 February 2012 and not 2 December 2012?

Here is what I have in the controller method:

The GET method

```
public ActionResult AddAssignment()
{
    var satqry = db.Satelites.Select(c => new 
                                   {
                                       c.SateliteID,
                                       c.SateliteName
                                   });
    var wmqry = db.JustUsers
                  .Select(u => new 
                                   {
                                       u.name,
                                       u.RealName
                                   })
                  .OrderBy( u => u.RealName);

    SateliteSchedule satsched = new SateliteSchedule();

    satsched.Tanggal = DateTime.Now.Date;


    ViewBag.SatList = new SelectList(satqry.AsEnumerable(), "SateliteID", "SateliteName");
    ViewBag.WMList = new SelectList(wmqry.AsEnumerable(), "name", "RealName");


    return View(satsched);
}
```

The HttpPost method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddAssignment(SateliteSchedule SatSched)
{
    var txt = "";

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (SatSched.ID == 0)
        {
            db.SateliteSchedules.Add(SatSched);
            txt = "{0} has been added!";
        }
        else
        {
            db.Entry(SatSched).State = EntityState.Modified;
            txt = "{0} has been modified!";
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        Utility utl = new Utility();
        TempData["message"] = string.Format(txt, utl.GetSateliteName(SatSched.SateliteID));

        return RedirectToAction("FormAssignment");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "ModelState is not Valid!";

        return View("ErrorView");
    }
}
```

The view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddAssignment", "admin", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID);

   <table>
     <tr>
       <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Tanggal)
       </td>
       <td>
           @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Tanggal)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Tanggal)
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SateliteID)</td>
       <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("SateliteID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SatList, "--- Satelite ---")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SateliteID)
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.WMOnDuty)</td>
       <td>
           @Html.DropDownList("WMOnDuty", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.WMList, "--- Worship Manager ---")
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.WMOnDuty)
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SMOnDuty)</td>
       <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SMOnDuty)</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.WLOnDuty)</td>
       <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.WLOnDuty)</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MLOnDuty)</td>
       <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MLOnDuty)</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SoundMan)</td>
       <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SoundMan)</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td valign=top>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Note)</td>
       <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Note, new { @class = "memo-text" })</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
    <div>
       <input type="submit" value="Save" />
       @Html.ActionLink("Kembali", "FormAssignment")
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if adding this to my.ini and restarting mysql changes anything:

```
[mysqld]
date_format="%Y%m%d"
datetime_format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But after adding date_format to [mysqld] section the mysql service cannot be started.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the now date format as follows:
Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")

Good luck with the Satelites,

Cerveser

Comment: Thanks for the respon, but I don't have the problem with the date format. The problem is while the display show 12 Feb 2012, after save it, it change become 02 Dec 2012.